# Flash->php->Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, flash

aqui estou eu com mais uma questão de actionscript, vou ser bem objetivo.
No flash desenhei um automóvel, as 2 rodas são 1 botão, que quando clicado efetua uma consulta sql a uma tabela com campos iguais ao nome do botão criado para as rodas. O problema é o flash e php com action script 3. Sugestões?

Comment: Ola @dev. Qual e o problema especificamente? O Flash, o PHP ou o MySQL? Ocorre algum erro? Veja [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) como criar um exemplo completo mínimo e verificável.

Answer (score 0):

Ao fazer um pedido para um servidor remoto, o Flash precisa de verificar em primeiro lugar o arquivo da política *cross-domain* para apurar se os pedidos a partir do teu domínio são permitidos.

Se tens acesso ao servidor remoto, podes fazer o *upload* de um arquivo com o nome `crossdomain.xml` para conceder o seu acesso à aplicação.

Informações detalhadas em:

## [Cross-domain policy for Flash movies](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14213.html)

#### Exemplo 1

Arquivo de política a dizer aos servidores para permitir o acesso a filmes em Flash hospedados em `http://www.example.com`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
    <allow-access-from domain="www.example.com" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

#### Exemplo 2

Arquivo de política especificando aos servidores que devem permitir o acesso a filmes em Flash hospedados em `http://www.example.com`, escrito com ou sem `www`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
    <allow-access-from domain="www.example.com" />
    <allow-access-from domain="example.com" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

#### Exemplo 3

Arquivo de política que concede o acesso ao Flash Player, independentemente do sub-domínio que faz a requisição, por meio de uma *wild card* `*` no campo da *token* do sub-domínio:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
    <allow-access-from domain="*.example.com" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Comment: Obrigado Zuul, mas o que queria mesmo era o cógigo.